# How can i change port number of mysql 8.0 cmd line client in windows?

Tags: mysql

How can i change **port** number of **mysql 8.0** cmd line client in windows?? **changing mysql port number**

Comment: Please show us an example of what you are trying to do - and why - and what tool you are using.  Maybe we can go from there.  if it's just mysql --user x --host y syntax, then there is a --port option for that.  Hopefully you've looked at the manual?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting.html

> To specify a port number explicitly, use the --port or -P option:
>
> mysql --host=remote.example.com --port=13306

... or show an example.